# transform vs transformDeferred

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams, spring-reactor

What is the difference between `transform` & `transformDeferred` in project reactor flux.

Good example will be helpful.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#advanced-mutualizing-operator-usage

Comment: read about hot and cold publishers https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactor.hotCold you switch between them using the `deferred` keyword.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most of the time, a `Flux` is "lazy": you *declare* a processing pipeline, but data only starts flowing once you **subscribe** to it. You can subscribe multiple times.

This is called a *cold* `Flux` (and each time you subscribe to a cold source, the source generates its data anew for the benefit of the new subscriber).

So we can distinguish:

- **assembly time**: the moment where we call operators on a `Flux` instance, returning a new `Flux` instance
- **subscription time**: the moment where that instance is subscribed to. Actually, the moments (plural), since there could be multiple subscriptions which could be far apart.

`transform` is a convenience method to apply a set of operators to a given `Flux`. For instance, you want all your `Flux` returned by methods of a service to use `.log("serviceName")`, so you externalize this trait in a `static Function<Flux, Flux>`:

loggingTrait = f -> f.log("serviceName");`

Now you can apply this trait in all Flux-returning methods of the service via `transform`.

It is applied immediately, right at assembly time. Since subscribers come after, they all "share" the same result of the function.

Now imagine you'd like the logging to eg. include the time of subscription, or another piece of data that is more dependent on each individual subscriber.

That's where `transformDeferred` comes in: it *defers* the application of the `Function` to the moment where the subscription occurs. Plus, it applies the `Function` for EACH subscription.

So you could do something like:

```
loggingTrait = f -> f.log(serviceName + "@" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

And the logs category would be different for each subscriber.

Comment: Did I get it right? If I call `transform()` with `loggingTrait = f -> f.log(serviceName + "@" + System.currentTimeMillis());` then each subscriber will log the same time and it will be the time when `transform()` called?