# Spring WebFlux : Timeout Handler invoked even when it hasn't timed out

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to understand why the timeout handler is invoked in below code. Since, I had configured the timeout of 100 seconds, I wasn't expecting the handler to be invoked as the element was being emitted after 1 second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.just(1).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    integerMono
     .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100),handler())
     .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer));

    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }

  private static Mono<? extends Integer> handler() {
    System.out.println("handler invoked");
    return Mono.just(10);
  }
```

below is the output :

```
handler invoked
1
```

can someone please explain, why it's behaving so, and how do we achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877616/6051176

Answer (score 2):

Your `handler()` method is invoked every time you call it. It's a simple Java method that creates `Mono` object. But this `Mono` will be subscribed only after timeout.

You can change your handler method like this to test it:

```
private Mono<? extends Integer> handler() {
    System.out.println("Handler assembling");
    return Mono.just(10)
            .doOnSubscribe(subscription ->
                    System.out.println("Handler subscribed"));
}
```

There is a [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription) about assembly and subscription differences.

[That SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711972/transform-vs-transformdeferred/63827850#63827850) could be helpful too.